# Simply getting a new EC2 windows instance up and running hosting a simple Hello World web app, and unable to connect to it from any other machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Problem: Simply getting a new EC2 windows instance up and running hosting a simple Hello World web app, and unable to connect to it from any other machine

Ok, I feel foolish asking this, as I've gotten this to work many times for years.  But today, for no discernable reason, I am stumped.

New Windows Server 2022 base instance.
Run simple .net web app listening on port 80
Locally browse to http://localhost and it works fine
Turn on Firewall rule to allow port 80
In AWS Security Groups, allow port 80

Test with the public IP:  Site cannot be reached

Disable Windows Firewall completely: same result

Use an alternative port, 5001, 8080, allowing them in the firewall, and with AWS security rules: same result

Try from another EC2 instance in the same subnet: same result

Make sure that locally the simple web app is working: yes

As I mentioned I feel like I am missing some critical and obvious thing.

Please be **kind**, as I have tried many solutions for this and am hitting a wall, and am humbly asking for help, not ridicule.

Here is the firewall of and connecting locally:

[image]

Here is the security groups:

[image]

Here is the subnet network ACL:

[image]

Here is the not connecting:

[image]

Comment: Since you are connected over RDP, it means either the security the group or the subnet ACL is not allowing traffic on the required port

Comment: @Paolo I added  a screen shot of the security groups.  As for ACL in the subnet, this is the same subnet I use for all the other servers in this VPC.   And the Inbound Rules allow all traffic from all sources by default.

Comment: Try using the ip:port explicitly, e.g. `52.38.234.126:8080` (or whatever port the app is running on)

Comment: Ok tried that, still no luck.    I even moved from Server 2022 to Server 2019, which my other ones are.  Besides Firewall is there anything else on the Windows side I could be missing?

Comment: OK here is a clue - this machine does not have IIS on it. I'm not running an IIS app - but could it be that there are services and things IIS sets up which are needed?

Comment: Nah, IIS cannot be it. The app runs fine locally.  No IIS needed at all. And netstat tells me that it's running on my port as expected.

Comment: I have followed this, to no avail:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319653/problems-connecting-to-public-ip-address-from-ec2-instance

Comment: OK, got IIS running, and it works just fine externally on ports 80, 5001, and 5002.  But a simple Web API (the weather forecast app), works locally, but not externally. No other changes.

Comment: Try running `netsh http add iplisten 52.38.234.126`

Comment: That did not work but in my .net app I replaced:  app.Run("http://localhost:5001") with  app.Run("http://0.0.0.0:5001") and it works!  I do not quite understand why.

Comment: Here's why https://stackoverflow.com/a/20778887/3390419

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  I was running my aspnet.core app using:

`app.Run("http://localhost:5001")`

But should have been using:
`app.Run("http://0.0.0.0:5002")`

The first tells the app to listen ONLY on IP 127.0.0.1, while the second says listen on ALL IP addresses.

After much searching I found the clue here:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/28/external-network-access-to-kestrel-and-iis-express-in-aspnet-core

Specifically this:

*In order to expose Kestrel externally you either have to bind to a specific machine name, IP Address or 0.0.0.0 which stands for all IP Addresses (thanks to @DamianEdwards and @BradyMHolt for their help).*

So it really is just these threes main things needed:

- Windows Firewall allow port
- App running on port
- AWS Security Rules for port

However, the way the the application binding is made is critical!

This is also helpful:
[What is the difference between 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost)